# Rest webservice not returning any results

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jcr, modeshape

I have a webservice which searches for pieces of texts in modeshape content repository.
The interface looks something like this :

```
 @POST
    @Path("globalSearch")
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String globalSearch(String search) {
        XMLConverterService xmlOb = new XMLConverterService();
        Map<String,String> param = xmlOb.fetchMapFromXml(search);
        StringBuffer xmlString = new StringBuffer();
        xmlString.append("<xml>");
        int count = 0;
        List<Map<String, String>> result = (new DataInterfaceService())
                .fetchGlobalSearch(param);
        if(result!=null){
        for (Map<String, String> map : result) {
            count++;
            xmlString.append("<result" + count + ">")
                    .append(xmlOb.fetchXmlFromMap(map))
                    .append("</result" + count + ">");
        }
        xmlString.append("</xml>");
        return xmlString.toString();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

the fetchGlobalSearch() function looks something like this :

```
public List<Map<String, String>> fetchGlobalSearch(Map<String, String> param) {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "entering fetchGlobalSearch");
    String keyWord = param.get("keyword");
    String type = param.get("type");
    List<Map<String, String>> listOfMaps = null;
    Map<String, String> retValue = null;
    String qry = "";
    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("GRA")) {
        qry = "SELECT [med:UNIQUE_ID],[med:GRPNAME],[med:CSR],[med:UW],[med:GROUP_STATE],[med:STR_DATE] "
                + "FROM [med:notes] where contains([med:XML_STORE], $uuid)";
    } else {
        qry = "SELECT [fur:UNIQUE_ID],[fur:MM],[fur:FROMUW],[fur:INSURED],[fur:POLICY_NUM],[fur:UWCSRDATE],[fur:FURCOMPDATE],[fur:FUR_DATE],[fur:CSRCOMPDATE] "
                + "FROM [fur:notesfur] where contains([fur:XML_STORE], $uuid)";
    }
    try {
        Query qr = qrym.createQuery(qry, Query.JCR_SQL2);

        Value uid = session.getValueFactory().createValue(keyWord);
        qr.bindValue("uuid", uid);

        QueryResult resultSet = qr.execute();
        String[] columns = resultSet.getColumnNames();

        RowIterator rowiter = resultSet.getRows();

        while (rowiter.hasNext()) {
            if (listOfMaps == null)
                listOfMaps = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            retValue = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Row row = rowiter.nextRow();
            for (String column : columns) {
                if (row.getValue(column) != null) {
                    retValue.put(column, row.getValue(column).toString());
                }
            }
            listOfMaps.add(retValue);
        }

    } catch (RepositoryException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "exiting fetchGlobalSearch");
    return listOfMaps;
}
```

I access the webservice by following piece of code :

```
private static void callGlobalSearch(){
        try {
            String param = "";
            param = fetchGlobalParams();
            System.out.println("param : " + param);
            // Create a socket connection to the host
            URL url = new URL(
                    "http://localhost:8080/xxttrr/rest/globalSearch");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // make url connection
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(param.getBytes().length));
            DataOutputStream printout = new DataOutputStream (conn.getOutputStream());
            printout.writeBytes(param);
            printout.flush();
            printout.close();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;            
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            in.close();
            conn.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }

    }
```

The problem is when I make a webservice call to my local modeshape repository, the result is returned as expected. but when I deploy the code in my DEV server it forms following log :

```
14:32:47,033 INFO [DataInterfaceService] (http-/0.0.0.0:8380-1) entering fetchGlobalSearch
14:32:47,035 DEBUG [org.modeshape.jcr.query.optimize.RuleBasedOptimizer] (http-/0.0.0.0:8380-1) Running query optimizer rule org.modeshape.jcr.query.optimize.RewritePseudoColumns@580ba9a4
14:32:47,036 DEBUG [org.modeshape.jcr.query.optimize.RuleBasedOptimizer] (http-/0.0.0.0:8380-1) Running query optimizer rule ReplaceViews
14:32:47,036 DEBUG [org.modeshape.jcr.query.optimize.RuleBasedOptimizer] (http-/0.0.0.0:8380-1) Running query optimizer rule CopyCriteria
14:32:47,037 DEBUG [org.modeshape.jcr.query.optimize.RuleBasedOptimizer] (http-/0.0.0.0:8380-1) Running query optimizer rule RightOuterToLeftOuterJoins
14:32:47,037 DEBUG [org.modeshape.jcr.query.optimize.RuleBasedOptimizer] (http-/0.0.0.0:8380-1) Running query optimizer rule AddAccessNodes
14:32:47,037 DEBUG [org.modeshape.jcr.query.optimize.RuleBasedOptimizer] (http-/0.0.0.0:8380-1) Running query optimizer rule PushSelectCriteria
14:32:47,037 DEBUG [org.modeshape.jcr.query.optimize.RuleBasedOptimizer] (http-/0.0.0.0:8380-1) Running query optimizer rule PushProjects
14:32:47,037 DEBUG [org.modeshape.jcr.query.optimize.RuleBasedOptimizer] (http-/0.0.0.0:8380-1) Running query optimizer rule AddOrderingColumnsToSources
14:32:47,038 DEBUG [org.modeshape.jcr.query.optimize.RuleBasedOptimizer] (http-/0.0.0.0:8380-1) Running query optimizer rule RewriteAsRangeCriteria
14:32:47,038 DEBUG [org.modeshape.jcr.query.optimize.RuleBasedOptimizer] (http-/0.0.0.0:8380-1) Running query optimizer rule RewritePathAndNameCriteria
14:32:47,039 DEBUG [org.modeshape.jcr.query.lucene.LuceneQueryEngine] (http-/0.0.0.0:8380-1) Executing the lucene query: +(::wks:System ::wks:Default) +:ft:ddd:XML_STORE:"uuid" +jcr:mixinTypes:ddd:notes
14:32:47,051 INFO [DataInterfaceService] (http-/0.0.0.0:8380-1) exiting fetchGlobalSearch
```

and terminates.

Is it something to do with modeshape configuration or webservice?
Just to let you know, at a point there might be a million records in modeshape. so is the timeout causing an issue. if so, then how can I configure my webservice so that it can live for say 5 mins?

Any help would be appreciated.
It's really confusing as to how the same code behaves differently in different servers.

Comment: Some of the most important parts are missing - where's the guts of the rest service?   Also, you don't want the service trying to return 'millions' of rows of data.  You will need to paginate the results somehow to make the service more usable.

Comment: Hi Mikemil,
the webservice doesn't return million records. It just searches within a million records. at a time the webservice should return max 20 records. I have pasted the code of the interface in my main post. hope it helps you figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was nothing. the error said it all. Apparently uuid should not be used as a variable name for passing parameters to SQL2 queries. changed it to uid and it worked like a charm.